# Supply parameters to NUnit tests at run time

Tags: testing, nunit, nunit-2.5

[NUnit 2.5](http://nunit.net/) adds support for parameterized tests with attributes like `ValuesAttribute` and `ValueSourceAttribute` so that one can write something like:

```
[Test]
public void MoneyTransfer(
    [Values("USD", "EUR")]string currency,
    [Values(0, 100)]long amount)
{
}
```

and get all permutations for parameters specified. Priceless. However, it would be cool to specify (override) those parameters directly in NUnit GUI before pressing 'Run'. Unfortunately there is no such functionality in NUnit (yet?). Is there an alternative tool or testing framework allowing me to specify parameters before running a test (something like i can provide parameters in [WcfTestClient.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx))?

Comment: Is the goal to give people (potentially non-coders?) the ability to run tests by supplying their own parameters for a given test run? Is there a problem with just keeping all the possibilities they might enter in the test?

Comment: Exactly! Our coders mostly work with a dummy implementing the agreed interfaces but on the integration phase sometimes non-tech people should be able to try some use cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option could be to try out the [TestCaseSource](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5) attribute that's supported - basically, you can define an IEnumerable method as source of data for a test - and within that, you can look anywhere you like for test data - could be to pull from a database/flat file/iterater round files in a given directory etc.

Have a look at that, it's a handy thing to know about.

Answer (score -1):

Unit test are supposed to run automatically and be reproducible. By changing test at runtime you break this behavior.
So I don't think this is something you want to do...

Comment: I need this primarily for integration testing

Comment: This should be a comment - it is not an answer. 
If the OP is asking a question, it's fair to assume there is a good reason for them asking it.   
There are reasons why you might not want to run a whole suite of tests during development.